# Glassfish Log4j JNDI: Cannot find appender

Tags: web-services, spring, log4j, glassfish-3, jndi

I am using Glassfish and I created a JNDI custom resource called log4j that has these properties:

```
Name: log4j.appender.LOG Value: org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
Name: log4j.appender.LOG.layout Value: org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
Name: log4j.rootLogger Value: WARN, LOG
Name: log4j.appender.LOG.layout.conversionPattern Value: %d{MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss} %p %m%n
Name: log4j.appender.LOG.File Value: ${com.sun.aas.instanceRoot}/logs/RestWebServices.log
Name: log4j.appender.LOG.MaxFileSize Value: 10MB
Name: log4j.appender.LOG.MaxBackupIndex Value: 10
```

The JNDI resource type is java.util.Properties and my spring application context contains these lines to find them:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="log4jJndi" jndi-name="log4j" resource-ref="true" />
<jee:jndi-lookup id="configurationsJndi" jndi-name="configurations" resource-ref="true" />

<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="propertiesArray">
        <list>
            <ref bean="configurationsJndi"/>
            <ref bean="log4jJndi"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

It works fine for my configurations JNDI resource but log4j gives me this error when starting Glassfish:

```
SEVERE: log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).  
SEVERE: log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.  
SEVERE: log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

When debugging the root logger was not the one I set in the JNDI resource. I tried adding the spring Log4jConfigListener to resolve this but it did not work. The version of Glassfish I am using is 3.1.

Does anyone know why log4j is an issue?

Edit: Now I am try to use JNDI that has the file location to my log4j properties file and my Spring application context gets the value from JNDI. My problem is I keep getting this error all the time with log4j:

```
Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException:  
ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'log4jJndi': Invocation of init method failed; 
nested exception is javax.naming.CommunicationException: Communication exception for SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessException: value cannot be null]|#]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following see if that helps:

1- create a file call it log4j.properties and place it in /src/main/resources

2- Copy the following lines in that file:

```
# #Default log level
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, console

log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p %d [%t] %c: %m%n

################################################
# #You can set custom log levels per-package here
################################################

# #Apache Commons tend to make a lot of noise which can clutter the log.
log4j.logger.org.apache=WARN

# #Shuts up some innocuous messages if using the JBPM transport
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.engine.StatefulPersistenceContext.ProxyWarnLog=ERROR

# #Reduce startup noise
log4j.logger.org.springframework.beans.factory=WARN

# #Your custom classes if you have one
log4j.logger.com.mycompany=DEBUG
```

Comment: We had a properties file originally in the application but wanted it in the container. That is why I reference JNDI custom resource in Glassfish.

Comment: Is there a log4j.xml in /src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/? You'll see that warning if log4j can't find a file "log4j.properties" or "log4j.xml" anywhere.

Comment: No I am just using the JNDI custom resource. In the Glassfish Admin Panel under that resource I added the properties there. So it is not in a file.